Appending data to json file
When I am calling the writeToJsonFile function method, it's writing properly to the file, but when I am calling UpdateJSONFileData, instead of appending the data to file it's overwriting.
The objective here is to write the data to file by either passing directly key and value or by passing the object
public static void writeTojsonFile(String key, 
                                   String value, 
                                   String fileName, 
                                   Object object)
{
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
try{
  FileWriter file = new FileWriter(filePath);
  if(object == null)
  {
     jsonObject.put(key, value);
     file.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
     file.flush();
   }
 else
 {
     objectMapper.writeValue(new File(fileName), object);
  }
}catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}}

public static void UpdateJSONFileData(String Key, 
                                      String value, 
                                      String filePath, 
                                      Object object) throws
                                           FileNotFoundException, 
                                           IOException, 
                                           ParseException {

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
ObjectNode objectNode = new ObjectNode(null);
objectNode = objectMapper.readValue(new File(filePath), objectNode.getClass());
if(object == null)
   {
       objectNode.put(key, value);
       objectMapper.writeValue(new File(filePath), objectNode);
   }
else{
       objectMapper.writeValue(new File(filePath), object);
    }
}

Currently I am calling the function method as
writeTojsonFile("Role", "Engineer", "/src/employeeInfo.json", null)

JSONObject empInfo = new JSONObject();
empInfo.put("ID","1234");
empInfo.put("Name","John")

UpdateJSONFileData("","", "/src/employeeInfo.json", empInfo)

Required output is:
{"Role":"Engineer","ID":"1234", "Name":"John"}

but it's overwriting as:
{"ID":"1234", "Name":"John"}


You have to read the OLD object into a JSONObject, then update your fields, then write the entire updated object out.  It sounds to me like you need to abandon JSON and use a real SQL product.

@vss – error: ';' expected ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()                                               ^

@Armali, in my editor its there, here it is a typo mistake.

Meh. What is the else branch supposed to do? You pass in an object and write it do the file. The file is read but not touched. Do yourself a favor and split UpdateJSONFileData to two functions.

Though the below will append the object, I am not sure why you want to write two independent JSON object to a file. May be you are writing a one-json-per-line file.
//The if block rewrites the file, there is no problem here
if(object == null)
   {
       objectNode.put(key, value);
       objectMapper.writeValue(new File(filePath), objectNode);
   }
//The else block also rewrites the file as well. Reason is when the
//OutputStream is opened by Jackson, it is not in append mode
//Try opening the file stream in append mode 
//FileOutputStream(File file,boolean append)
//and use ObjectMapper.writeValue(OutputStream out,Object value)
//flush and close the stream
//That should address the issue, give it a try
else{
       objectMapper.writeValue(new File(filePath), object);
    }
}

